# OCaml, several questions

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have many questions connected with OCaml ?

1. How to compile code ? I desire to have a .exe file (I'm working on windows)
2. How to use #use ? In one folder I have two files:
   file1.ml and file2.ml
   And file2.ml contains #use "file1.ml", but compiler cannot find file1.ml. What should I do ?

Comment: Please ask separate questions separately, and please do not ask easily Googlable questions such as "how to compile code"... come on.

Comment: I have just one question: did you try reading any ocaml tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

1. Try `ocamlc` or `ocamlopt`
2. `#use` is a toplevel directive. When relying on the compiler to create an executable, files are compiled separately and then linked, just like with compilers for most other languages.

Comment: OK, so what I should do If I would like to use "things" from other file ?

Comment: @user3052477 Read this: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora130.html This is what Google turns up for “ocaml separate compilation”. If you find it involves OCaml concepts you  are not familiar with, read the previous chapters.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to learn OCaml, please refer to this book:

https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/index.html

It was out weeks ago and it is currently the best book about OCaml. And its HTML version is free.